Cannot access a mindsDB DB
I cannot use the database from mindsdb on my local MYSQL.
i use the
host: localhost 
port: 47334

this is the command on execute on powershell
mysqlsh -h 127.0.0.1 -P 47334 -u mindsdb -p

result in this error
MySQL Error 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060

I just trying connect and select on mindsDB local databasse
Obs:
I run in docker desktop and the mindsDB container work fine
